# Using sstableloader to load migrate cassandra cluster

Tags: amazon-ec2, cassandra

I am trying to migrate a cassandra cluster from a dedicated DC to EC2. I took a snapshot of the sstables as a start. To load the data, I tried sstableloader in the process, but I am not able to figure a way to to specify the hosts from my cassandra node (I am trying to run sstable loader from my cassandra node). Any guidance would be really helpful. I am using cassandra 1.0.1.

Answer (score 1):

sstableloader in cassandra 1.0.1 uses gossip protocol to get schema and ring info needed to bulk load. This means that the tool have to listen on the same port as cassandra itself, thus it cannot be used in the same node with cassandra(this is not the case for cassandra > 1.1).

You need to bulk load from other host, or follow the direction in here(http://www.datastax.com/docs/1.0/operations/backup_restore) to load snapshot straight to new node.
Also, you can bulk load files in the node using existing cassandra node through JMX "bulkLoad" operation found under StorageService MBean.

Comment: So, if I bulk load from a different host using the sstableloader, how will I give the path to the sstable files. Because I thought that the path needs to be on the system from which sstableloader.

Comment: Does sstableloader load just part of the data? I have cluster1 with 3 nodes and cluster2 with 3 nodes. I need to copy data from cluster1 to cluster2. Do I have to run sstableloader on each cluster1 node or sstableloader does get all parts of table from other hosts for me?

Comment: sstableloader handles which part of the data goes to which node. It first contancts the node (specified in '-d' option) and gets ring information. Then it streams part of SSTables to appropriate node.